# Ubuntu Server 18.04 installer does not show partitions

Tags: dual-boot, server, partitioning, system-installation, 18.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 to dual boot with Windows. When I run the Ubuntu Server installer, it doesn't show any partitions on the disk and instead recognizes my entire disk as unformatted.

Following the instalation [tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server), everything happens exactly as shown, except I never got past [step 8](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server#8), as trying to use the manual configuration shows my entire disk.

I've seen various questions about this and it seems to be related to errors on the partition table, thus fixed by gdisk. In my case, gdisk doesn't report any errors, and the report doesn't show overlapping partitions (as that also seems to be related).

After concluding it might not be a problem with my disk, I tried the Ubuntu Desktop installer, and it recognized all the partitions perfectly (in fact I installed it and am using it to try to fix this right now).

Is there anything the Ubuntu Server installer does differently from Ubuntu Desktop that I should be aware of (as far as I know they both use libparted), or am I missing something?

---

(I've seen something about zapping the GPT table, but I really don't see a reason to risk doing that if Ubuntu Desktop had no problems with it)

Comment: Just added information about the tutorial. Edited the title again, as it doesn't show any partitions, not even the ext4 I created for installing Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: Do not zap gpt partitions if you still want Windows and it is booting in UEFI boot mode. Did you boot installer in UEFI mode? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Sure, [here it is](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JyTRZmWzzG/). sda6 and sda7 are the ones I want to use for the installation. Besides that, there's my main windows partition, and two windows repair partitions.

sdb2 seems to have a problem, but I'm using grub without problems, so I'm not sure about that.

Comment: And I forgot to answer it, but yes, I boot it in UEFI mode.

Comment: Swap partitions are obsolete; all you need is the root partition as swap file performance now meets swap partition performance.

Comment: They're not going to fix this in 18: [see the Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1680245) Last note (Jan 1, '19) says "It's on the roadmap for 19.04.”

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Ubuntu Server installer
If you require advanced networking and storage features such as; LVM, RAID, multipath, vlans, bonds, or re-using existing partitions, you will want to continue to use the alternate installer. ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64.iso

[cdimage.ubuntu.com](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.1/release/?_ga=2.216911318.1326991330.1546761399-1730719602.1542831362)